# Switched from immediate mode to VBOs, game runs slower

Tags: opengl, c++, optimization, vbo, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to improve the draw performance on my `c++`, `OpenGL`, `SDL` game.

Back in school we mostly learned immediate mode, so that's how my drawing was originally implemented. When I started reading up online about improving performance, I read about `VBOs` and how they are 'so much better' and use the graphics card memory, etc.

So I took a couple of nights and converted to them. When I tested the game, it actually ran slower (draw method went from ~7 to ~10 ticks).

Did I do something wrong or are VBOs only more efficient in certain situations?

Here's my class for tessellated polygons after adding VBOs (my game draws a lot of flat 2D shapes in a 3D world, sort of papermario-style)

```
#include "Tesselator.h"

Tesselator::Tesselator(std::vector<b2Vec2> vertices, Gradient* gradient) {
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->gradient = gradient;
    tesselator = gluNewTess();
    gluTessCallback(tesselator, GLU_TESS_BEGIN_DATA, (void(CALLBACK*)())beginCallback);
    gluTessCallback(tesselator, GLU_TESS_VERTEX_DATA, (void(CALLBACK*)())vertexCallback);
    gluTessCallback(tesselator, GLU_TESS_END, (void(CALLBACK*)())endCallback);
    int vertcount = (int)vertices.size();
    GLdouble vertarray[vertcount][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        vertarray[i][0] = vertices[i].x;
        vertarray[i][1] = vertices[i].y;
        vertarray[i][2] = 0;
    }
    gluTessBeginPolygon(tesselator, this);
    gluTessBeginContour(tesselator);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        gluTessVertex(tesselator, vertarray[i], vertarray[i]);
    }
    gluTessEndContour(tesselator);
    gluTessEndPolygon(tesselator);
    gluDeleteTess(tesselator);
    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i++) {
        triangleVBOs.push_back(new VertexBufferObject(triangles[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < trianglefans.size(); i++) {
        triangleFanVBOs.push_back(new VertexBufferObject(trianglefans[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < trianglestrips.size(); i++) {
        triangleStripVBOs.push_back(new VertexBufferObject(trianglestrips[i]));
    }
}
Tesselator::~Tesselator() {
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleVBOs.size(); i++) {
        delete triangleVBOs[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleFanVBOs.size(); i++) {
        delete triangleFanVBOs[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleStripVBOs.size(); i++) {
        delete triangleStripVBOs[i];
    }
    triangleVBOs.clear();
    triangleFanVBOs.clear();
    triangleStripVBOs.clear();
}
void Tesselator::draw(float z) {
    Drawing::applyZTranslation(z);
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleVBOs.size(); i++) {
        triangleVBOs[i]->draw(GL_TRIANGLES);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleFanVBOs.size(); i++) {
        triangleFanVBOs[i]->draw(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleStripVBOs.size(); i++) {
        triangleStripVBOs[i]->draw(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    }
    Drawing::applyZTranslation(-z);
}
void Tesselator::addTriangle() {
    std::vector<b2Vec2> triangleVertices;
    triangles.push_back(triangleVertices);
}
void Tesselator::addTriangleFan() {
    std::vector<b2Vec2> triangleFanVertices;
    trianglefans.push_back(triangleFanVertices);
}
void Tesselator::addTriangleStrip() {
    std::vector<b2Vec2> triangleStripVertices;
    trianglestrips.push_back(triangleStripVertices);
}
void Tesselator::addVertex(b2Vec2 vertex) {
    if (currentType == GL_TRIANGLES) {
        triangles.back().push_back(b2Vec2(vertex.x, vertex.y));
    }
    else if (currentType == GL_TRIANGLE_FAN) {
        trianglefans.back().push_back(b2Vec2(vertex.x, vertex.y));
    }
    else if (currentType == GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) {
        trianglestrips.back().push_back(b2Vec2(vertex.x, vertex.y));
    }
}
void CALLBACK Tesselator::beginCallback(GLenum type, GLvoid * tessdata) {
    Tesselator* tess = (Tesselator*) tessdata;
    tess->currentType = type;
    if (type == GL_TRIANGLES) {
        tess->addTriangle();
    }
    else if (type == GL_TRIANGLE_FAN) {
        tess->addTriangleFan();
    }
    else if (type == GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) {
        tess->addTriangleStrip();
    }
}
void CALLBACK Tesselator::vertexCallback(GLdouble* vertex, GLvoid* tessdata) {
    Tesselator* tess = (Tesselator*) tessdata;
    tess->addVertex(b2Vec2(*(vertex), *(vertex + 1)));
}
void CALLBACK Tesselator::endCallback() {
}
```

and here is my vertex buffer object class

```
#include "VertexBufferObject.h"

VertexBufferObject::VertexBufferObject(std::vector<b2Vec2> shapeVertices) {
    numberOfCoordinateValues = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeVertices.size(); i++) {
        numberOfCoordinateValues = numberOfCoordinateValues + 2;
    }
    float coordinateValues[numberOfCoordinateValues];
    int coordinateValueArrayIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeVertices.size(); i++) {
        coordinateValues[coordinateValueArrayIndex] = shapeVertices[i].x;
        coordinateValueArrayIndex++;
        coordinateValues[coordinateValueArrayIndex] = shapeVertices[i].y;
        coordinateValueArrayIndex++;
    }
    glGenBuffers(1, &id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(coordinateValues),     coordinateValues, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
VertexBufferObject::~VertexBufferObject() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &id);
}
void VertexBufferObject::draw(GLenum mode) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(mode, 0, numberOfCoordinateValues/2);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

and heres what the draw method for Tesselator used to look like before adding VBOs

```
void Tesselator::draw(float z) {
    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.size(); i++) {
        Drawing::drawTriangles(triangles[i], z, gradient);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < trianglefans.size(); i++) {
        Drawing::drawTriangleFan(trianglefans[i], z, gradient);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < trianglestrips.size(); i++) {
        Drawing::drawTriangleStrip(trianglestrips[i], z, gradient);
    }
}
```

and in Drawing.cpp:

```
void Drawing::drawTriangles(std::vector<b2Vec2> vertices, float z, Gradient* gradient) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        addVertex(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, z, gradient);
    }
    glEnd();
}
void Drawing::drawTriangleFan(std::vector<b2Vec2> vertices, float z, Gradient* gradient) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        addVertex(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, z, gradient);
    }
    glEnd();
}
void Drawing::drawTriangleStrip(std::vector<b2Vec2> vertices, float z, Gradient* gradient) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        addVertex(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, z, gradient);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

You ar still using old school glBegin/glEnd for drawing, this is not going to be faster.

You need to bind the buffer, push data to the VBO after changing it, and then draw with said buffer. This will most likely decrease your drawtime. Also, try and find geometry that does not change and create a static VBO for all that data, push it to the gpu. Now you only need to bind the buffer and draw it.

[1] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object

Comment: I think you misread the post. You are reading from the part of my code that was replaced

Comment: I only posted the old code before implementing VBOs for comparison "and heres what the draw method for Tesselator used to look like before adding VBOs... and in Drawing.cpp:"

Comment: That is correct, I totally missed the text in between explaning before and after - sorry! Going from glBegin/glEnd to glBindBuffer et al and not decreasing the time it takes to render is wierd. It is really hard to say what might cause this.

Comment: so i figured out that i was running OpenGL 2 all this time, not sure why the vbos still "worked", but i guess that explains why they weren't improving performance. anyways I'm asking SDL to use 4.1 now, game runs faster (i think, based on my cout printing ticks taken for the draw method), but i can't see anything, just a blank screen with my clear color... I was using glColor4f() to set the color before drawing the VBOs, is that completely non functional in OpenGL 4? i know its sort of being phased out by shaders but shouldn't those older functions still work?

Comment: To phrase my long winded question into something simpler, can the older functions (intermediate mode glColor etc) still be used in newer OpenGL alongside the new stuff? or does it force you to only use the latest and greatest (VBO, shaders) and the old stuff is completely non functional

Comment: Those functions are all deprecated since 3+ core as can be read in the Wikipedia article about OpenGL. I guess adding an color to your vertices could help, or just for debugging - change clear color to non-black; this should give you black lines when rendering.

Comment: after reading up on this more, it seems VBOs were introduced in OpenGL 2, so i guess the version thing was a bit of a wild goose chase. as long as OpenGL 2 accepts VBOs and still lets me do all those other things (glColor etc), I'm happy with staying on that version, I'm just still left with the puzzling question of why VBOs actually ended up making the game run slower, could it be that I'm using glColor and old drawing methods in combination with VBOs? I'm just setting glColor once and before drawing each VBO

Comment: I recommend downloading a OpenGL debugger such as CodeXL by AMD. It's hard to give any further advice without knowing more about the code of your program in general. There might be something that is slowing things down that is not directly related to VBOs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36058/discussion-between-gosso-and-dylan).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36097/discussion-between-dylan-and-gosso).

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people think, that every aspect of the VBOs are fast, that's not really true. Binding a VBO is very slow. Always make sure, you bind VBOs one time, then render the same model multiple times with different position, rotation, etc.